# Replace a key in GSON

Tags: json, gson

I'm new to GSON. I have a JSON object (As a String) -

```
{
"name" : "myName",
"city" : "myCity"
}
```

I parsed this as follows -

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json_result = (JsonObject)parser.parse(#TheAboveMentionedStringGoesHere);
```

Now I want to replace the key `name` with something else ,say, `firstName` so that the resulting JSON object is -

```
{
"firstName" : "myName",
"city" : "myCity"
}
```

Is this possible? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+` Google GSON third party library, and then according to it's [documentations](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md), you can use `@SerializedName("commits_url")`in the model class or POJO.
So your model class might be like below :

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("first_name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("city")
    String city;
}
```

and also when you want use it as :

```
Gist gist = new Gson().fromJson("{
"firstName" : "myName",
"city" : "myCity"
}", Gist.class);
```

at last if you think you need to use customized Serialiazer and Deserializer, please read [this documention](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
json_result.add("firstName", json_result.get("name"));
        
json_result.remove("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json_result = (JsonObject)parser.parse(#TheAboveMentionedStringGoesHere);
```

have another similar object with a constructor that takes JsonObject as its parameter, but has firstname as its field name.

```
public class json2{
    String firstname;
    String city;
    public json2(JsonObject){
        this.firstname=JsonObject.name;
        this.city=JsonObject.city;
    }

}

json2 j = new json2(JsonObject);
String jsonString = Gson.toJson(j);
```

You will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

The following function will search through an object and all of its child objects/arrays, and replace the key with the new value. It will apply globally, so it won't stop after the first replacement

```
function findAndReplace(object, value, replacevalue){
  for(var x in object){
 if(typeof object[x] == 'object'){
  findAndReplace(object[x], value, replacevalue);
 }
 if(object[x] == value){
  object["name"] = replacevalue;
  // break; 
 }
}
}
```

Please check the Below Link

[JS](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/qLTB7/61/)