# Is it possible to declare a string / int as numer?

Tags: java, json, string, gson, declaration

I want to parse JSON in Java, but my JSON lookslike this:

```
...
{
    "total_count": 16,
    "entries": [
        {
            "2": "1788",
            "3": "Yes", 
            "id": "2009131"
         },
         {
            "2": "956",
            "3": "No", 
            "id": "1381"
         }
...
```

I already figured out to "extract" the entries by:

```
if(jsonTree.isJsonObject()){
            System.out.println("True");
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();

            JsonElement f2 = jsonObject.get("entries");
```

Now I've a JSON array. For parsing with gson, I would need a class with variables like this (at least I think so):

```
int 2;
String 3;
```

which isn't declarable as far as I know.

Is there a way (prefix, syntax?) to implement anyways? Or another way to extract and assign the values with the right id?

Comment: You might be looking for `@SerializedName`. https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize POJO to JSON with different names using GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547662/serialize-pojo-to-json-with-different-names-using-gson)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469788/replace-a-key-in-gson

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SerializedName` annotation which allow to define field name different than property name in `Java` file. Below you can see example how to deserialise your `JSON` payload to `Java` model:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Root root = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Root.class);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}

class Root {

    @SerializedName("total_count")
    private int totalCount;
    private List<Entry> entries;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Entry {
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("2")
    private String two;

    @SerializedName("3")
    private String three;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Root{totalCount=16, entries=[Entry{id='2009131', two='1788', three='Yes'}, Entry{id='1381', two='956', three='No'}]}
```

If your `JSON` is dynamic and can have more/less keys you can deserialise it to `Map<String, String>`:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Root root = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Root.class);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}

class Root {

    @SerializedName("total_count")
    private int totalCount;
    private List<Map<String, String>> entries;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Root{totalCount=16, entries=[{2=1788, 3=Yes, id=2009131}, {2=956, 3=No, id=1381}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an object "Entries" and have all possible variables there.  There are JSON libraries that can do the transformation for you.